# image extracted from database not getting displayed in a div in php

Tags: php

i want to display a picture in my picture div. I have coded as given below.

```
<div id="picture">
       <?php
       @session_start();
       $email=$_SESSION['email'];
        include "db.php";
        $query2=mysql_query("select profilepicture from registration where email='$email'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($query2)>0)
         {
          while($rowtwo = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
           {
            echo '<img src="'.$rowtwo["profilepicture"].'" style="height:180px" />';
           }
         }
       ?>
      </div>
```

and the given below is my code where I uploaded my picture in database and a folder named uploads

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
     {
      $changefname=$_POST['changefname'];
      $changelname=$_POST['changelname'];
      $changeprofilepic=$_FILES['file']['name'];
      $tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
       if(!empty($changefname)&&!empty($changelname)&&!empty($changeprofilepic))
        {
         $location='uploads/';
         if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$changeprofilepic))
          {
           //echo "uploaded";
           session_start();
           $email=$_SESSION['email'];
           include "db.php";
           $query=mysql_query("update registration set fname='$changefname', lname='$changelname', profilepicture='$changeprofilepic' where email='$email'");
           header('location:homepage.php');
          }
        }
     }
   ?>
```

When I click on save button it does not display a full picture but a small icon.. 
Please help me

Comment: $rowtwo["profilepicture"] only retrieve image name.Please provide the complete path before displaying

Comment: You have to give folder path as well like uploads/$rowtwo["profilepicture"]

Comment: what you get in $rowtwo["profilepicture"]  ?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule  **session_start();**  should be at the start of the code before PHP  outputs anything and then you won't need @ to suppress error messages !